# MASM Assembly 8086 - Implementing division without use DIV instruction for any number

Tags: algorithm, math, assembly, cpu-usage, division

I'm trying to implement a division operation without using DIV instruction for performance reasons. I saw this link: 
http://what-when-how.com/microcontrollers/multiplication-and-division-microcontrollers/
and in the code of division operation (is not Assembly 8086) I don't understand what it does.
I try to write the code with the corresponding ASM 8086 instructions hoping that I don't wrong. 
In that example we have B --> Dividend (BX) and A ---> Divisor (AX)

```
DIVIDE: PSHA (PUSH AX) ;Save the divisor
        CLRA (XOR BX,BX) ;Expand dividend, fill with zeros
        LDX #8 ;Initialize counter (I don't understand this part, maybe initialize a counter = 8 because we have here 8 bits)

LOOP: ASLD ;Shift dividend and quotient left (?? SHL BX,1 ?)        

      CMPA 0,SP ;Check if subtraction will leave positive result (?? Subtraction between?)
```

and I stop here because if I don't understand this part is useless going ahead.
Can you help me? There is another division algorithm better than DIV instruction?

Comment: If you could outperform a dedicated division instruction for arbitrary numbers, the CPU's microcode would already do this. Really you're only going to find special cases where you can substitute something else (e.g. bit-shifts for powers of two, testing the least significant bit instead of division to test for even/odd, etc.) and come out on top.

Comment: What  is the target micro-controller?

Comment: The divide instruction on 8086 is fairly fast. If dividing by a constant, you can create the inverse of the number as a fractional (decimal or binary point on the left of the number), then using a 16x16 multiply to produce a 32 bit result, will produce the quotient (or close to it) in the upper 16 bits, and you may have to adjust it, usually just an increment. There are other "clever" inverse of constant methods, that could be used depending on the number of significant bits in the constant divisor.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called the "Russian Peasant Algorithm" and can be implemented using shifts and addition. However, it's not going to buy you any performance on a machine with a dedicated divide instruction. I implemented it on an 8051 years ago, but that didn't have multiply / divide instructions, so it made sense. You're not going to outperform microcoded  multiplication and division in regular assembly code. They've already spent the time to optimize the div instruction quite heavily.

Comment: I second this. If you look at the # of cycles necessary for the performance of one MUL or DIV, it's is possible for it to be 1 cycle in recent architectures. This is because of modern pipelining, out-of-order execution, and multiport ALUs. And I'm ignoring the SIMD operations that have been around since Pentium and have moved into the embedded world.